# How to setup a Windows Phone App without a tile title

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I set no title to my app, like the Facebook app, since my app also have its name displayed in the logo ? I tried in the app properties in Visual Studio but it displays an error saying that the title should not be empty.

To clarify : I want the app tile not to display the app title.

Comment: Have you tried putting spaces in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the `WMManifest.xml` in the `Properties` folder.

Find this:

```
<Tokens>
  <PrimaryToken TokenID="AppToken" TaskName="_default">
    <TemplateType5>
      <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Background.png</BackgroundImageURI>
      <Count>0</Count>
      <Title>YOUR APP TITLE HERE</Title>
    </TemplateType5>
  </PrimaryToken>
</Tokens>
```

And change the `Title` element to

```
<Title></Title>
```

Done. No more title displayed on the tile when pinning your app.

[Example to prove it's possible](https://github.com/Windcape/GOTOcon/blob/master/GotoCon/Properties/WMAppManifest.xml)  (This is a app that's available on the marketplace)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have your primary application title without a title, though I believe that through Push Notification services it has been possible to remove the title.

If you are creating a Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango) application, you could try using the [ShellTile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltile_members%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) API to set the title to an empty string. The primary tile is the first value returned by the **ActiveTiles** property if the application is pinned to the Start screen.

Comment: No no, he just wants the `Title` in the `TemplateType5` token inside `WMManifest.xml` to be blank.

Comment: I didn't think that was acceptable in the Marketplace? I thought it would fail certification for that. I guess I was wrong :(